# jhipster client cannot run,server side success

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster

this is my server side jdl file, this is success

```
    application {
      config {
        baseName preview
        packageName com.jinmed.preview
        devDatabaseType mysql
        cacheProvider ehcache
        authenticationType jwt
        skipClient true
      }
      entities *
    }
    entities and relationship...
```

this is client side,this is failed,i have tried a lot time change configure,i dont know the reason

```
    application {
      config {
        baseName previewBoot
        devDatabaseType mysql
        cacheProvider ehcache
        authenticationType jwt
        skipServer true
      }
      entities *
    }

    entities and relationship...
```

Answer (score 0):

it just because my very complicated entities and relationships ,if there someone want to see it, i will paste id on

Comment: Your application is of type microservices? U can paste all your jdl? Is one file o two?

Comment: its too big ,i can't paste it here ,you can see from here :https://github.com/scott929/scott929/blob/master/relationfile

Comment: I don't see problems with your entitys. I think that u don't create your application correctly, u create the application with questions or with file? What's is the error message in the log? Please update your information with this.

Comment: really thank you for spending time to anaysis this problem,i update this file,in fact i create the application with file,now it has been update:https://github.com/scott929/scott929/blob/master/relationfile